# Informal word for canned food / tin cans

Tags: terminology, formality, synonyms, north-american-english

Is there an informal word commonly used in North American English for canned food? I’m looking for something that might be used by a youngster to describe such a meal.

In Germany, we have *[Dosenfutter](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dosenfutter)*, which has a connotation that sort of reminds one of canned pet food.

This is needed for a work of fiction.

Comment: If you want to be faintly disparaging, I think "tinned" could work, but maybe more so in Canadian English than US English. "Tinned peaches", for example, sounds worse than "canned peaches" (the latter could be factory or home-preserved in a glass mason jar)

Comment: The simple answer is "no there isn't such a word", or if there is I have not heard it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany 'Tinned' is rather more common in British English than 'canned' when referring to food. Incidentally 'canned' isn't used for food preserved in glass in the UK, we tend to call it 'bottled'.

Comment: In German you can combine words to make those lovely long German compounds, which can then sometimes evolve to have a slightly different connotation than their original literal meaning, as you describe with "Dosenfutter." In English we don't get to do that, and I can't think of a single word that captures your very clearly stated connotation. There's a classic visual example of what you mean in the movie "Repo Man," where throughout the film there are cans and boxes with white labels and black lettering such as a can that says "Food" and a pop-top that says "Beer." It all looks unappetizing.

Comment: In most of the US the term is "canned food".  "Tinned" is British and sounds odd to the average American ear.  (Though I do recall the term being used in a few old westerns, so it might have been idiomatic in the US 150 years ago, or that may simply have been script writers looking for an archaic-sounding term.)

Comment: If you want to imply a canned meal, it might be best to say something like "I've invited Chef Boyardee to dinner".  (There are one or two other iconic canned food names besides "Boyardee", but they're not coming to me just now.)

Comment: @HotLicks - like Dinty Moore

Answer (score 1):

One word that is used in this context to refer to tinned food in this context is [spam](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=spam). That is not a reference to junk email, but the food variety, which refers to "spiced ham" that was produced from the leftovers of pork cuts and "tinned" in this manner.

Originated in the late 1930s, it became a "staple" during World War II (which featured "short rations"), but became an "inferior good" by comparison when better food became available after the war.

Comment: See Monty Python for the definitive word on *Spam* (the meat, well sort of).

Comment: Note that *Spam* is the trademarked name for a particular company's product.  (It's canned about 50 miles from here.)

Comment: (And, to most in the US, if one says "We're having Spam for dinner", that implies that, indeed, the canned ham product will be served, not a meal of random canned foodstuffs.)

Comment: Note that in Hawaii  a meal consisting of or including *spam* is still very popular today (they serve it in McDonald's). Technically I guess Hawaii is not part of North America, but it is a state in the United States and both American English and pidgin are spoken there.

Answer (score -2):

You write to describe a "meal" but North American English speakers more often  than not only get a part or a component of a meal from a can — vegetables, beans, liquids, sauces, fillings, etc.

Notable exceptions are soup, chili, macaroni with sauce (Chef Boyardee). In these cases, "a can of (item)..." is said.

Comment: Doesn't really address the user's question.